# Reorganizing folders without missing files history

Tags: git, mv

When I move some files using OS native command or GUI, git loses the tracks and think files are deleted and new files are created! Using git `mv` command its works. But it does not support moving folders or wild cards (does it?)

What is the best way to reorganize files and folders without missing of their history?

Answer (score 0):

Git by design does not record file renames, but rather computes the history of a file at runtime. This has the consequence that there's no such thing as a "best way" to reorganize files/folders; admittedly, however, since Git determines renames by comparing the contents of files, it does have the effect that, if you want to move a file *and* modify its contents, it's better to have one commit which contains only file renames and another commit for the content modifications.

For flags relevant to how Git computes renames, see the `-C` and `-M` options of `git log`.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the protocol of git, how we move files before `git commit` affects little. A commit is effectively a snapshot of all files, and does not contain differences from previous commit.

This means we cannot really "track", but have to "recover" move of files.

Some git commands (and maybe GUIs) actually do this quite well. This is a git command I use to list change of files, including move.

```
$ git log --follow -- [FILES]
```